# How to make NuxtJS/Vuetify components take up a percentage of their parent container?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a NuxtJS component using Vuetify that has 1) a "window" for displaying messages, and 2) a text field for sending a new message. The messages window uses the vue-chat-scroll plugin, which is meant to make the component scrollable when it overflows with messages. These two components are both located within a parent container panel.

I'd like for the message entry field to align to the bottom of the parent container panel. The rest of the parent container should be filled by the messages window. I tried doing this by hardcoding both the messages window and entry field to use screen's vertical height. And the result was not capable of adapting to different screen sizes. Using % didn't change their heights at all.

Here is the current state of this component:

[image]

And the code...

**PARENT CONTAINER**

```
<template>
<v-container fluid class="content-body chat-panel">
  <v-row style="margin-bottom: 0;">
    <v-col align="center" style="margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;">
     <h3>Player Chat</h3>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12">
      <MessagesWindow :topicId="topicId" />
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" v-show="userType != 'o'" style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0;">
      <MessageBox :topicId="topicId" />
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
</template>
```

**And their styles**

```
.content-body.chat-panel {
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 1vw !important;
    padding-right: 1vw !important;
    padding-top: 2vh !important;
}

.chatPanel-window {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.chatPanel-box {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

How can I achieve aligning the message entry field to the bottom of the parent container, and having the rest of the parent container taken up by the messages window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CSS `flexbox`.

You can should the `flex-direction` to `column` to stack the children,

set the `justify-content` to `flex-end` to align the children to the bottom

and `flex-grow` to `1` on the messages window, so it takes up all extra available height

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-body.chat-panel {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 2vh 1vw 0 !important;
}

.chatPanel-window {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.chatPanel-box {
  padding: 0 auto !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-body chat-panel">
  <div class="chatPanel-window" style="background-color: grey;">Messages</div>
  <div class="chatPanel-box">Input</div>
</div>
```